# Is there a good way to get the daily step count in real-time on an Android smartphone?

Tags: android, sdk, google-fit

I was trying to get the daily step count using the Google Fit API. However, as Fitness.getHistoryClient has been deprecated, I had to look for another method. On https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryClient, it is recommended to use Health Connect. However, it is stated that the Health Connect app must be installed on the smartphone. Since most users do not have Health Connect installed, I had to find another way. Is there a simple way to get the daily step count like before?

```
Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, account)
        .readData(readRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener { response ->
            val dataSet = response.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.dataType.name)
            for (dp in dataSet.dataPoints) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Data point:")
                Log.i(TAG, "\tType: " + dp.dataType.name)
                Log.i(TAG, "\tStart: " + DateFormat.getInstance().format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
                Log.i(TAG, "\tEnd: " + DateFormat.getInstance().format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
                for (field in dp.dataType.fields) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "\tField: " + field.name + " Value: " + dp.getValue(field))
                }
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure()", e)
        }
```

That method is reportedly no longer available.

Comment: you can use a simple sensorlistener:


val stepSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)
        val stepListener = object : SensorEventListener {
            override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
                  val steps = event?.values?.get(0)?.toLong()
}

unfortunately this returns the step count after a boot. so to get the daily step count you have to check the date and store a value if the date changes. 

this is way faster then google health which returns stepcount in the background only every half an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Health connect app will be system app from Android OS 14, and they also informed to developer migrate googlefit api to health connect.
This is example:
https://github.com/android/health-samples